# Why does 'az vm secret format' command fail when prepping SSL cert of Linux VM deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am trying to prepare an SSL certificate for deployment to Linux VM hosted on Azure following the instructions provided at:

[HTTPS access to Azure ubuntu Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807954/https-access-to-azure-ubuntu-virtual-machine)

The first line:

```
$secret=$(az keyvault secret list-versions --vault-name myVaultName --name myCertName --query "[?attributes.enabled].id" --output tsv)
```

executes fine, and $secret contains the expected value.  However when I execute the second line:

```
$vm_secret=$(az vm secret format --secret "$secret")
```

I get an error:

```
unable to find vault 'myVaultName' in current subscription.
```

I have double-checked the command format and parameters and can find nothing wrong.  What going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a strange thing. The CLI command works fine before, but now it needs to add the parameter `--keyvault` with the key vault name and `-g` with resource group name like this:

```
$vm_secret=$(az vm secret format --secret "$secret" -g groupName --keyvault keyvaultName)
```

Or just add the parameter `--keyvault` with the key vault Id:

```
$vm_secret=$(az vm secret format --secret "$secret" --keyvault keyvault_resourceId)
```

So that it can work fine without giving the error.

Note: if you use the old key vault created serial months ago, the CLI command that giving the error would also work in my test. So it's a little strange. And I find there is something different with the properties default value.

### EDIT

I think it's better to run CLI command in a Linux environment, there is something different that CLI rin in Windows and Linux, it's possible to cause the error. And the script in Linux will like below:

```
az keyvault certificate create --vault-name keyvault_name --name cert_name --policy "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy)"

secret=$(az keyvault secret list-versions --vault-name keyvault_name --name cert_name --query "[?attributes.enabled].id" --output tsv)

vm_secret=$(az vm secret format --secrets "$secret" --resource-group group_name --keyvault keyvault_name)

az vm update -g charles -n azureUbuntu18 --set osProfile.secrets="$vm_secret"
```

Comment: Many thanks indeed.  I assume by the keyvault_Id you mean keyvaultname?  If I use your changes the command now executes and the value of $vm_secret looks reasonable - note I had to use $vm_secret *not* vm_secret.  If I now run the next step (az vm update -n vmName -g vmResourceGroup --set osProfile.secrets="$vm_secret") I get a deserialization error (Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [VaultSecretGroup]...). Any ideas?

Comment: The keyvault_Id means the resource Id. Then the variable format `vm_secret` is set up in Linux. In Windows, you can set it as `$vm_secret`.

Comment: There is something different between windows and Linux. In Linux, the variable `vm_secret` is a string type and it works fine. In windows, it's System.Array type. You can run the script in Azure Cloud Shell, then run the script. Take care, in Linux, there should no `$` as a prefix for the variable.

Comment: When I do the az vm update I get the same exact error whether I use $vm_secret or just vm_secret (both with or wihout the enclosing ").  Error starts: Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [VaultSecretGroup] an object of type <class 'str'> and ends with: msrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [VaultSecretGroup] an object of type.

Comment: @ProfNimrod Yeah, I know that error. I mean you can execute the script in Azure Cloud Shell with a bash environment. It can work fine. I guess there would be something not good when the CLI command run in Windows system.

Comment: Thanks for checking in.  I haven't tried to run the command in a bash environment yet.  I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Using the commands in your EDIT nearly worked.  I got an error associated with the VM and the Cert being in two different locations (North Central US and West US).  I didn't realize they had to be in the same regions, so will try again once I have them in the same region.