# How do I add HTTPS to Docker contained website running on Azure Linux VM?

Tags: azure, docker, ssl, azure-virtual-machine, azure-linux

I have an existing WordPress website running inside a docker container on a Azure hosted Linux VM.  I have followed the instruction at [Why does 'az vm secret format' command fail when prepping SSL cert of Linux VM deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336531/why-does-az-vm-secret-format-command-fail-when-prepping-ssl-cert-of-linux-vm-d/54338365#54338365) so that the SSL certificate has been associated with the VM, and port 443 is also open on the VM.

How do I now associate the SSL cert to the WordPress application running in the Docker containiner hosted on this Linux VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the Linux VM with the certificate, then certificates and keys are stored in the protected /var/lib/waagent/ directory. It shows in the document [SSL Certificates Add to Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server#create-a-cloud-init-config-to-secure-nginx). You can find the certificate and mount it to your container like this:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/waagent/yourcert:/container/to/path/cert -d --name containerName yourImage
```

Then you can use the certificate in your container for your application as you wish.

**EDIT**

The certificate in the directory will show like this:

[image]

Not the name that you create in the Key Vault.

Comment: Looks like we're on the right track here.  I can see the *crt and *.prv files for my cert in /var/lib/waagent as you indicate.  What do you mean by /container/to/path/cert ? Where would this typically be? Or is this simply my choice. Is containerName the container id obtained when 'docker ps' is run?  Sorry for the very basic questions.  I'm a total newb when it comes to Linux.

Comment: The path /container/to/path/cert means you can the path as you want, it's all dependent you. And I mean you can mount the cert to the container when you create it.

Comment: @ProfNimrod Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.